# Runtime error when running meteor

Tags: meteor, installation, runtime-error

I did a meteor install for the first time a week ago. Everything worked like a charm.

Today I open up a terminal and tried typing meteor and get:

```
module.js:117
    throw e;
          ^
SyntaxError: Error parsing /home/mike/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/fibers/package.json: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at readPackage (module.js:113:48)
    at tryPackage (module.js:123:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:190:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mike/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/meteor.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

I assumed that somehow meteor was messed up. so I tried to reinstall it and get:

```
module.js:117
    throw e;
          ^
SyntaxError: Error parsing /home/mike/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/lib/node_modules/fibers/package.json: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at readPackage (module.js:113:48)
    at tryPackage (module.js:123:13)
    at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:190:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:25)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mike/.meteor/tools/0b2f28e18b/tools/meteor.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

How do I fix my meteor install?

Comment: I fixed it by uninstalling: rm -rf ~/.meteor/ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/meteor

and reinstalling:

curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

And all code works again.

Comment: As far as I remember, this is also how I fixed it when I came across this one. Better write down your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted. That way, people who come by this post will know.